# iOS 8 ALAsset setImageData doesn't delete image

Tags: ios, alasset, photolibrary

I am working on iOS 8 Photo Library application. I want to delete image from photo library using ALAsset setImageData to nil. But method is not working. Please help me out.

Comment: Use Photo Kit on iOS 8.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "not working". Are you getting an error back via the API, or in the Console, or in the app log?

Comment: It does not delete the image from the photo library.